# I don't want to repeat all time the function Connect_DB() in different Forms C#

Tags: c#, function, class, include

because I want make this function just 1 time. Like C++ with include headers. How can I do it in C# and call it from another class? I tried to make a class but i don't know.

```
    private void connect_BD()
    {
        cs = @"datasource=localhost;
               port=3306;
               userid=XXXX;
               password=XXXX;
               database=XXXX";
        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

my connection class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace BuscaMinas
{
    class conection
    {
        static MySqlConnection connection;
        String cs = null;

        private void connect_BD()
        {
            cs = @"datasource=localhost;
               port=3306;
               userid=XXXX;
               password=XXXX;
               database=XXXX";

            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Specify a scenario please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a static function that returns a instance of a new MySQLConnection like;

```
public class Database
{

    public static MySqlConnection Connect()
    {
         static MySqlConnection connection;
         String cs = null;            

           cs = @"datasource=localhost;
           port=3306;
           userid=XXXX;
           password=XXXX;
           database=XXXX";

        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Log error...;
        }

        return connection;
    }

}
```

You could then call this like;

> MySqlConnection oMySqlConnection = Database.Connect();

and then check if the database connection has been opened like;

```
if (oMySqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
 ...
}
```

Once you have used the connection, you must remember to dispose/close it.  You can do this by calling

> oMySqlConnection.Close();

Comment: public MySqlConnection static Connect() is not valid syntactically.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public static MySqlConnection Connect()` ?

Comment: Yeah, you hit the "MySqlConnection" button before the "static" :D

Comment: Might want to add how to call and use the method since OP did mention that in his question ("How can I do it in C# and call it from another class"). :)

Comment: Using this method, callees are responsible for properly closing/disposing of the connection each time.

Comment: I cant use Database.Connect(); directly. I need create: DataBase db = new DataBase(); THEN MySqlConnection oMySqlConnection = db.Connect(); Is it correct?

Comment: Database.Connect(); is a static function, which means you don't have to create a instance of a object to call it.  Yes try MySqlConnection oMySqlConnection = Database.Connect();, like in the example